# Sql Query help need

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

Query1:

```
select accnt_no,sum(no_shares)Buy from psdr_cds
where accnt_no between 1 and 9999
and trans_dt between '1-jan-2000' and '1-dec-2011'
and comp_cd=101 group by accnt_no;
```

Query2:

```
select accnt_no,sum(no_shares)Sell from swr_cds
where accnt_no between 1 and 9999
and trans_dt between '1-jan-2000' and '1-dec-2011'
and comp_cd=101 group by accnt_no;
```

Final Query:

```
select i.accnt_no,i.ac_name1 from inv_profile i
where i.accnt_no in(select accnt_no from psdr_cds
where accnt_no between 1 and 9999
and trans_dt between '1-jan-2000' and '1-dec-2011'
and comp_cd=101
union
select accnt_no from swr_cds
where accnt_no between 1 and 9999
and trans_dt between '1-jan-2000' and '1-dec-2011'
and comp_cd=101)
```

Using the query1, query2 and final query I produced the result-

```
accnt_no    ac_name1         Buy         Sell        Balance
12          Prasun           300          150         150
34          Abc              300          0           300
```

Now i want to return the same result using single query instead this three query.
Can anyone help me about this?

Comment: question is not clear from where you get Buy, Sell, Balance?

Comment: Balance is difference between Buy(psdr_cds) -Sell(swr_cds)

Comment: It's pretty hard to follow this question.  The union in the "final query" looks like it's going to produce an error when you run it, for example (different number of fields selected), and I can't see exactly where you're getting "Buy", "Sell", and "Balance" in your result table.  Do you think you could clarify a bit?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without your data or schema I can't really test it, but I think this might do it:

```
SELECT i.accnt_no,i.ac_name1
FROM inv_profile i
LEFT JOIN psdr_cds p ON p.accnt_no = i.accnt_no
LEFT JOIN swr_cds s ON s.accnt_no = i.accnt_no
WHERE i.accnt_no between 1 and 9999
AND ((p.trans_dt between '1-jan-2000' AND '1-dec-2011' AND p.comp_cd=101)
OR (s.trans_dt between '1-jan-2000' AND '1-dec-2011' AND s.comp_cd=101))
```

Otherwise, I didn't see anything glaringly wrong with your UNION-based subquery.  While not optimal, it might end-up being the best way to go.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.At the first sight it looks accurate.